# Need help searching a pandas dataframe for a substring from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (called combos) that looks like this (where player_title is an index column, and Team , Opp are regular column headers )

| Player_Title | Team | Opp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QB Kirk Cousins | MIN | @ HOU |
| WR Adam Thielen | MIN | @ HOU |
| WR Justin Jefferson | MIN | @ HOU |
| RB Alvin Kamara | NO | @ DET |
| RB Myles Gaskin | MIA | vs SEA |
| WR Brandin Cooks | HOU | vs MIN |
| TE Logan Thomas | WAS | vs BAL |
| RB Kenyan Drake | ARI | @ CAR |
| DST Vikings | MIN | @ HOU |

I am trying to write a conditional statement that sees whether or not the "Team" for the DST row appears anywhere in the Opp column. If it does, return true. In this example it should return true because the Opp of WR Brandon Cooks is Min.

I used combo['Team'][-1] to find the value of Team, and I used combo['Opp'][:-1] to find the list of Opponents I am trying to search through for Min. Then plugged into a lambda function that didnt find the matching substring. Ideally this would return true/false so that I can use it in an if/else statement, but havent figured out how to do that.
combo['C'] = combo.apply(lambda x: x['Team'][-1] in x['Team'][:-1], axis=1)

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: The expected output should be True based on the sample data 
combo['Team'][-1] = 'MIN'
>>> combo['Opp'][:-1].str[-3:]
Player_Title
WR Brandin Cooks       MIN
I am trying to use it in an if/else statement and mozway's answer almost works except it returns False even though MIN exists  in the Opp field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
combo['Team'].iloc[-1] in combo['Opp'][:-1].str[-3:].values
```

Comment: I tried this but it the return statement comes out false instead of true, where I expected True for the sample dataset. I want to add that I also tried removing the vs and @ symbols to see if they were causing the misatch but that wasnt the case.

Comment: perfect thank you! 
A side note, I was testing while you were doing that and this also worked:
combo['Team'][-1] in str(combo['Opp'][:-1].str[-3:])